# Dell PowerEdge 1950 RAID Battery - what kind?

Tags: raid, dell, dell-poweredge, battery

What kind of battery do I need for a Dell PowerEdge 1950 RAID?

I am seeing an error code W1228 on the front which means <24 hours for the RAID battery.  Per the Dell manual it says I need to replace it and shows pictures and that it sits in a pouch next to drive bay 0.  However I have been unable to find a part number or some identifier so I can purchase the proper battery type.

Comment: Which RAID controller do you have? PERC 6/i?

Comment: Looks like a Perc 5/i

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dell lists [the replacement part for $49.99](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=biz&cs=555&sku=312-0448&baynote_bnrank=0&baynote_irrank=1&~ck=dellSearch).

- Manufacturer Part# : UF302
- Dell Part# : 312-0448

Comment: Roughly, how did you locate this?   I have looked through the support site using my service tag # and not found this part.

Comment: @Scott I went to this [Dell Support page](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/DellPartsFamily.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=k12), input my 1950's Service Tag in the "Option 2" field and clicked "search".  On the results page I selected the "Power" category -- the above part was listed there.  You may want to contact Dell directly if the search-by-tag doesn't work for your system.  It is possible the Perc was added after purchase, hence Dell not having detailed in their configuration.

Comment: Interesting, I do see it now, but it only shows me a refurbished version of the same battery.  http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=k12&cs=RC1084719&sku=NU209&mfgpid=167752&chassisid=8743&~ck=dellSearch&baynote_bnrank=0&baynote_irrank=4

Comment: @Scott TBH, I haven't the foggiest what voodoo Dell's support site may be doing in the background. :) You may want to remove your existing battery for a part/type number. It's also possible there are minor variations between controller/server revs that may affect Dell's recommended FRUs.  Sorry I can't be more helpful, and I certainly don't want to mislead you on this. You may want to contact Dell support directly.

Answer (score 3):

If you're unsure then why not speak to your sales rep? Mine is always very helpful when I have questions like this. Getting them the Service Tag number should be all you need to purchase a new one.

Comment: Yeah this isn't generally a 3V CMOS battery ...

Comment: No, I am sure it's a battery pack.  I replaced one in a Dell PowerEdge tower, but I am not sure if it's the same and was hoping it might be an easy answer for someone.

Answer (score 2):

There are two different Dell part numbers depending on the generation of you PERC Controller. A PERC 5/i RAID battery PN is U8735-A0 or A1 or A2 (consider these as date codes for manufacturing times). A PERC 6/i battery PN is NU209 (no date codes needed yet). Google any these and you will find resellers who specialize in selling these aftermarket. That being said there is an option in OMSA (Open Manage Server Administrator) to do a battery recondition as well before you go out and buy something you might not need. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

install the dell openmanager app and it will list all the parts and any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Open up the case and take a look.

I seem to recall that one of the PERC batteries was simply 3-AA batteries shrink-wrapped together. Dell charged $20 for this part, and I could obtain the same thing [Jameco.com](http://www.jameco.com/) for a fraction of the price.

But this may only be a good solution if the server is out of warrantee, and worth your staff time.